# Porting gcc without porting Binutils?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I am new to porting gcc, just want to ask, if I only want gcc to generate assembly language for each files can I skip porting Binutils ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Are you trying to port gcc as cross-compiler? You should configure with `--disable-bootstrap` and use `make all-gcc` when building it (i.e. skip libgcc, glibc, libstdc++ build). Then you will get pure compiler to work from source to target assembler only.